# Logic: Prove that if a set can be modelled then all its subsets can also be modelled

Tags: logic

I'm slightly confused by this question. I have to prove for

$$a = \{a_1, . . . , a_n\}$$

that if '$a$' is satisfiable/can be modelled then all subsets '$a_1$' to '$a_n$' are also satisfiable/can be modelled. I think that this has something to do with the compactness theorem, but when I search online everywhere says this direction is 'trivial' and so they don't prove it, which doesn't help me at all. Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A set $\Sigma$ of statements is satisfiable if there is an interpretation under which all of the statements in $\Sigma$ are true. So let $\Sigma$ be satisfiable and consider an interpretation that makes all of its statements true. If $\Sigma'\subseteq \Sigma,$ then under this interpretation, all the statements in $\Sigma'$ are true, since they are statements in $\Sigma$. Thus, $\Sigma'$ is satisfiable. So if $\Sigma$ is satisfiable, every subset of $\Sigma$ is satisfiable. Note we did not need need to stipulate that the subset is finite.

The compactness theorem is "if every finite subset of $\Sigma$ is satisfiable, then $\Sigma $ is satisfiable", which is going in the opposite direction.